# Java - Limiting Random outcomes based on earlier values

Tags: java, random

I'm working on a Gambler-like game to practice socket programming and I've ran into a slight problem. 
I have a game where the players take turn to get a random number. The numbers are added together to have Player Scores. I'm trying to make so that if you for example pull a 7 - you can't get it again. 
What I've been trying so far:
Edit:

```
private void pick() {

    Number r = new Number(getNumber(), new Vector2(200, 10));
    myNumbers.add(r);
    sendMessage(output, "Number" + r.value);
}

private int getNumber() {
    int n = random.nextInt(10);
    while(numberHasBeenPicked(n)) {
        n = random.nextInt(10);
    }

    return n;

}

private boolean numberHasBeenPicked(int value) {
    if(numbersUsed.contains(value))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

Also the `sendMessage()` function adds the numbers to the `numbersUsed` in both the server and the clients list so both programs knows which ones has been taken

/Edit

But I don't get the results I'm looking for. I don't know what more to say since the error I get is basically that I still get numbers that has been used even though I'm sure they have been put into the `numbersUsed` list.

Any help would be appreciated and I'm sorry if there is lack of information.

Comment: What is `numbersUsed`?

Comment: What do you think that `return false;` is doing in the `else`? Why not use `contains`, assuming `numbersUsed` is a `List`? Have you considered using a `HashSet`?

Comment: I had no idea about the contains method, thank you! The problem still remain however. I will read up on HashSet!

Comment: What is `myNumbers`? What is `numbersUsed`? Please provide a [mcve]. Also, revert your edit. Include your original code, and append the new one. You don't want to be invalidating answers.

Answer (score 0):

`while(!numberHasBeenPicked(n))`

you should delete `!` because when the condition is true, so the number has been picked, you want to pick another one. And by `!` you state: when it is false that the number has been picked (so it has not), pick another one. Seems like you want to achieve the opposite

Comment: As mentioned above this has now been fixed and the problem is still here, thank you for your response though!

Answer (score 0):

As @SotiriosDelimanolis mentioned it's better to change the design of your program. You can put all generated values into `ArrayList` and while generating new random numbers check if this `ArrayList` contains new number. You can do it with `containsAll()`